# Short circuit CASE/iif

Tags: sql, sql-server

I created a table valued function, which takes an optional parameter, which should determine whether a rather lengthy calculation (`PERCENTILE_CONT` in my case) should be run.

For this purpose I use a construct like this in my select statement

```sql
SELECT CASE @my_param 
       WHEN 1 THEN NULL 
       ELSE --run lengthy calc
       END
```

However, looking at the execution plan it seems that the lengthy calculation is triggered irrespective of how I set the parameter.

The problem can be reproduced with the following lines:

```sql
CREATE TABLE #temp(a int)
INSERT INTO #temp Values(1)
DECLARE @i INT = 1;
SELECT CASE WHEN @i=1 THEN 1
       ELSE PERCENTILE_CONT(0.5) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY a) OVER ()
       END
  FROM #temp
```

If you look at the execution plan, you will see that the `PERCENTILE_CONT` function is included irrespective of the value of `@i`. Since this very function slows down my query by a bit, I was wondering how to best circumvent that?

I tried to add an `IF` construct paired with an `UPDATE` statement in my function and while this avoids running the `PERCENTILE_CONT` function when not needed, it slows down the function when I want to include the `PERCENTILE_CONT` function. So what other options do I have to run `PERCENTILE_CONT` only in needed cases?

My median will eventually be calculated for several subgroups, thus I decided to go for `PERCENTILE_CONT` in the first place, knowing that it is not the best performance wise, but is very readable. Hence, while I appreciate hints of how to calculate the median in a more efficient way, I would also be curious to learn how to avoid or short circuit the calculation without the need to fall back to an ordinary `if` clause.

Comment: Use `if` logic to run two different versions of the query depending on the parameter.

Comment: Yeah that's what I tried. However in a flawed way. I created the normal query and `IF` the parameter is set, I ran an `UPDATE` which takes now twice as long. I did that b/c I wanted to avoid hardcoding the main sql twice (in each branch of the `IF`) with only one column being different (the `PERCENTILE_CONT`). So which pattern could I use to ideally defain the main query only once?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When SQL Server creates an execution plan for a query that uses an optional parameter, it has to generate a plan that is capable of handling both scenarios:

- where a value is provided for a specific parameter
- where no value is provided for that parameter

When a parameter is provided, it takes into account cardinality estimates based on that initial value (or lack of value), and then keeps *that plan* for subsequent executions (which is why performance can differ when the parameter values change but the plan remains the same).

This whole process gets exponentially more complex as you go from 1 to n optional parameters.

If you want to have one plan for the presence of a specific parameter, and another one for the absence, or even different plans compiled for different values of the param, you can use conditional logic [like Gordon suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63344159/short-circuit-case-iif#comment112009319_63344159) or you can follow [the kitchen sink approach](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/backtobasics-updated-kitchen-sink-example).

For example:

```
SET @sql = N'SELECT ...';

SET @sql = @sql + CASE WHEN @my_param = 1 THEN N'1'
  ELSE N'PERCENTILE_CONT(0.5) ... ' END;

...

EXEC sys.sp_executesql @sql;
```

I think this is a good balance between "one plan fits all" and "use `OPTION (RECOMPILE)` to get a new plan every single time." You can even add `OPTION (RECOMPILE)` to the dynamic SQL statement conditionally (for example you don't need it when the search ends up being a seek on a unique key, but it can make sense to have it when you might be searching for last name starts with S vs. last name contains Q).

Comment: Thanks very insightful and shows that I have still a long way to go. Thanks especially for the background explanation, which makes a good answer a great answer! +1

Comment: Only problem with this solution is that I cannot use it in a TVF. :(

Comment: Yes, that is true. No dynamic SQL inside a function (you also can't specify `OPTION()` in there). But you can reference an inline TVF in dynamic SQL and the logic gets folded into the outer plan, so depending on why/how you need your TVF, there still might be a solution. Or you might need to use a procedure instead of a TVF. Sometimes I want a car that flies, but I have to settle for a flight instead, because that's the best option available. :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can use Option (Recompile) to get the desired execution plan.

Please see the result in the screenshot below:

[image]

Comment: This works but it is wasteful if, for example, the same param is passed most or all of the time. On a busy system you will have a hard time convincing everyone else that all of your parameterized statements should have OPTION (RECOMPILE) all of the time.

Comment: @AaronBertrand right, Thanks! Option(recompile) should only be used when there is no other way of making a query better in terms of its performance.